# Magmi - Ignore attribute set if product already existists

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

Currently I'm building an automated import script with Magmi to import a CSV file on a scheduled basis.

The problem is that the CSV has only one value as attribute set (software restriction). So I've set this to **default**

But on the magento installation the products is updated by another plugin to get information from icecat. This plugin also changes the attribute_set in the magento store to match the right information.

My question is: How can I ignore the attribute_set in the CSV file of the product is already available in the magento store.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could accomplish this using Magmi plugin valuereplacer. Then define a replacement value for attribute_set using meta data to check wether it is new or not.

Take a look at this article: http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Value_Replacer

So, you would be having something like this in valuereplacer for column attribute_set:

```
{{ {meta.new} == 1 ?{item.attribute_set}:"__MAGMI_IGNORE__" }}
```

So, this translates into: if item is new, then use attribute_set from CSV source, else ignore.

This is untested but should get you somewhere. The MAGMI_IGNORE makes sure the attribute_set is not overwritten when the product is not new.

Comment: Looking good! I will test this solution. Just one other question. How to delete all products not available in the CSV without increasing the product ID numbers.

Comment: Hi, You mean delete from Magento database if they are no more in the CSV?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove them from the database (of disable them) if they are not present anymore

Comment: I see, I dont think this is possible natively with Magmi, but I have made a few Magmi plugins in the past, two of them are kind of exactly what you are looking for. I think that I even have the option to choose between disabling or deleting, but im not for sure, coded that quite a time ago. I`ll put the plugins up for download this weekend and comment the link here

Comment: Hi, So I put the plugins on my website: http://www.emvee-solutions.com/blog/magmi-delete-disable-products-missing-csv-source/ read the instructions to get started, I hope it works for you.

PS: you are allowed to upvote & accept my answer if it has helped you out ;)

Comment: Did this ever work for you?